# Coldfusion Decrypt with special characters

Tags: encryption, coldfusion

How to decrypt Coldfusion with standard algorithm and special characters ?

For example:

```
<cfoutput>#encrypt("123",key, "CFMX_COMPAT", "UU")#</cfoutput>
```

result: #-_G4

And if I try to decrypt this

```
<cfoutput>#decrypt("#-_G4",key,"CFMX_COMPAT", "UU")#</cfoutput>
```

I will get an error.
I know that in this example i should switch # to ##. But what should i do with other special characters in my database ? How to auto escape all special characters for the decrypt function ?

Comment: Have you tested it, it won't give an error. i just tested it and working fine. just define key properly.

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: Invalid CFML construct found on line 26 at column 26.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

/"

Comment: Try to crypt and decrypt "123" with key <cfset key = "15TLo47po">

Comment: Its working fine with above key. BTW which version of CF you are using? I am trying it on CF11 and 9.

Comment: CF 10. Ill try CF 11. Thank you for advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I will get an error. I know that in this example i should switch `#` to
>   `##`. But what should i do with other special characters in my database ?

Nothing. You can store whatever characters you want. You will not get that error when you invoke decrypt() with your query values.

*"Invalid CFML construct found.."* is a compilation error. It occurs before any CF code is even executed. The only reason it occurs in your example is because the `#` is embedded within the CF code itself. So when the CF server parses and compiles that code, it see the un-escaped # sign as the start of some sort of variable and looks for a closing `#` sign. When it does not find one where it expects, it causes an error and the compilation fails. So unescaped `#` signs are only an issue when they are contained *within* that actual CF code (or a string evaluated as CF code).

When you retrieve the encrypted text from the db table, CF does not evaluate the query values as code. It just pulls the strings from the db and hands them off to the decrypt function. So that error cannot occur.

Having said all that, **you really should not use CFMX_COMPAT - for anything**. It is not really encryption at all, but rather a legacy obfuscation algorithm maintained for backward compatibility only.  Instead use a real encryption algorithm like AES, Blowfish, etcetera. You might also want to use "base64" or "hex" instead of "UU", as they former are more portable. See the [`encrypt()` docs](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Encrypt) for a list of the supported algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

What are these CFMX_COMPAT IDs being used for?  I'd avoid using them since this algorithm only works with ColdFusion and is guessable.  If you want a safe, short, unguessable hashes for integers that can be used in URLs, Hashids is the best solution.

http://hashids.org/coldfusion/

This library is freely available for JavaScript, Ruby, Python, Java, Scala, PHP, Perl, CoffeeScript, Objective-C, C, C++11, Go, Lua, Elixir, ColdFusion, Groovy and for Node.js & .NET.  The ColdFusion CFC version wasn't compatible with ColdFusion 8, so I used the Java version on that server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that single # is creating the issue. Just store the output of your encrypted string in a variable and the place it for decryption. It will work.

```
 <cfset key = "15TLe44po">
 <cfoutput>#encrypt("123",key, "CFMX_COMPAT", "UU")#</cfoutput>
 <cfset encryptedText = encrypt("123",key, "CFMX_COMPAT", "UU") />
 <cfoutput>#decrypt("#encryptedText#",key,"CFMX_COMPAT", "UU")#</cfoutput>
 <cfabort>
```